# Serve images and static content from nodejs

Tags: node.js, image, gridfs

I'm building an app on nodejs in Ubuntu 20.

Mainly the app have to handle a series of cars that each user submit to the server through a form. Through this form the user specify the name of the car, the model, an image of the car and other informations ...

I manage the submitted image using gridfs and store them into mongodb with all the other datas.

[image]

Each time that a user load the site, a 30 rows table with the uploaded cars like the above one is displayed so the server must manage on each site route request

- reading the cars from the db
- rendering the html and it's css.minified - js.minified
- 35/40 requests for rendering the images of the cars in the table and other images

I'm thinking that this 35/40 requests for reading-rendering the images from mongodb can be handled from a secondary nodejs server instead of the main one that manage the app.

I need to make the main app lighter to allow more users on the site, and to do so my idea was to have 2 node applications

- The *main app* that serves the html pages and read/serve all the main informations, like the cars names etc..
- The *images app* that handle all the requests for upload/render the images

**But my concern is, Does this solution makes sense or it will only make the server busier to have two node applications instead of one?**

Answer (score 1):

Node really is designed for this type of architecture, and breaking up your services into micro-services is actually a good idea when it makes sense ( some will argue this point but personally I feel like the separation of concerns works well when you can scale horizontally for increased load)

Just a few comments ( take with a grain of salt) but..

1. I would not 'store' the image in the DB ( I'm taking this that you are storing a base64 object for the image?)
2. Use an object store like s3 to store your images
3. Use a CDN for static resources

If you architect your stack in such a way, and offload specific request to other services you can greatly reduce load AND increase scalability by not tethering the node server to 1 file system etc.

As an example, if you were to have a stack like

1. Front-end server that uses say ejs to render things to the client
2. processing server to do image uploads
3. Object store to store / serve images (static resources too, js, css etc)
4. DB server (postgres, mongo etc)
5. CDN to cache static resources
6. Redis to cache DB queries / API responses ( if needed )

The front end server should be able to run stateless, meaning it does not have any dependencies to the server (e.g images, css etc)

The processing server, this endpoint will just handle processing images, sending to the object store and updating the DB

The object store will house all images

DB serer to store data

The CDN will cache all request to further reduce server requests

Redis cache to cache API calls, again this is as needed and really depends on how you have it configured to pull your data, may or may not be needed.

The idea here is you are creating an application that can scale out horizontally and is now a great candidate for clustering, containers etc. Because each server has no dependencies to the server it can scale as needed to handle more load.